# Accessing Google Sheets API from Google Sites using 'embed': "Not a valid origin for the client" Error

Tags: embed, google-sheets-api, google-sites

I am trying to access a Google sheet using Google Sheets API. When I tried it locally, I was able to do it. When I tried the same from Google Sites by embedding the code, it gives me the following error.

```
{
  "error": "idpiframe_initialization_failed",
  "details": "Not a valid origin for the client: https://<dynamic-number>-atari-embeds.googleusercontent.com has not been whitelisted for client ID <client_id>. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."
}
```

As you can see from the error message, which I have edited to hide information, the origin of the embed is dynamic. So I can't update the whitelist on developer console.

Is there a way to solve this somehow?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have started your server?
If you are using python3 try this command on same directory where you have placed your index.html file.

```
python3 -m http.server 8000
```

For python2

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Then directly type
http://localhost:8000/index.html
No need to use LiveServer extention if you are using vscode.

Comment: The code is written in Google Sites, so don't need to start any server.